# Old Site displays on Mobile View, not New Site

Tags: css, mobile, responsive

I just relaunched a website from HTML to a responsive Wordpress site & theme. It's great on desktop, but folks who have visited via mobile before the relaunch are still seeing the old site.

**

### How New Visitors See the Page:

** http://www.marctech2.com

[image]

I have inserted viewport code (in both meta & css)

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

@viewport{
    zoom: 1.0;
    width: extend-to-zoom;
}

@-ms-viewport{
    width: extend-to-zoom;
    zoom: 1.0;
}
```

I have also submitted the site to Google crawl, and submitted the sitemap via Google webmaster tools.

Is there code I can insert that will instruct mobile viewers to automatically clear their cache?

My clients don't want to announce their new site because returning visitors might see the old one, and I mean, they have a point: We don't know who's been there or not, and even if we did, what are we going to do? Email instructions on clearing caches to the world? Customers don't read technical emails, and even if they did, it looks unprofessional.

Answer (score 0):

Have you uninstalled any WP mobile plugins like WPtouch?

Also, your header image isn't fully responsive.

Comment: I'm using Revolution Slider and don't see where to make my header image fully responsive. Am I looking in the wrong place?

Comment: Also, I'm not convinced I need something like WPtouch, as the problem isn't that there is no mobile version. The theme I'm using (Highend) is responsive. I have also asked on their support forum, but they all see the new site on mobile as they have nothing for it in their cache.